# Query always returns one empty row?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query always returns at least one row even if none is found

```
(
    SELECT accounting.time, enclosure.enc_id_, enclosure.txt, accounting.amount AS sum, SUM(ROUND(vatcode.percent/(100+vatcode.percent)*accounting.amount)) AS sum_vat
    FROM accounting
    INNER JOIN enclosure ON enclosure.id=accounting.enc_id
    LEFT JOIN vatcode ON vatcode.id=accounting.vatcode_id
    WHERE accounting.account_id='10'
)
UNION (
    SELECT accounting.time, enclosure.enc_id_, enclosure.txt, accounting.amount*-1 AS sum, NULL AS sum_vat
    FROM accounting
    INNER JOIN enclosure ON enclosure.id=accounting.enc_id
    WHERE accounting.accountoff_id='10'
) ORDER BY time
```

I know that the error occurs in the second select here `... , NULL AS sum_vat`.. If I remove it I get an error about not having the same statements in both select? How can this be solved?

return

```
Array
(
    [time] => 0
    [enc_id_] => 0
    [txt] => 
    [sum] => 0
    [sum_vat] => 
)
```

Comment: What does the returned row look like?  Could you add some sample data?

Comment: updated question.. if the `sum_vat` is removed from both select none rows are returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use an aggregate without a group by, the aggregate will run over the entire table, always returning a single row.  For example,

```
select max(price) from items where group = 'Servers'
```

returns a single row with the highest price.  MySQL is the only database that allows other columns without a `group by`:

```
select name, max(price) from items where group = 'Servers'
```

But confusingly, it would just put a random value in name column; the name here won't be the name of the highest priced server.

In your case, the obvious solution is to add a `group by` to the first part of the union:

```
SELECT accounting.time, enclosure.enc_id_, enclosure.txt, accounting.amount sum, 
    SUM(ROUND(vatcode.percent/(100+vatcode.percent)*accounting.amount)) sum_vat
FROM accounting
INNER JOIN enclosure ON enclosure.id=accounting.enc_id
LEFT JOIN vatcode ON vatcode.id=accounting.vatcode_id
WHERE accounting.account_id='10'
GROUP BY accounting.time, enclosure.enc_id_, enclosure.txt, accounting.amount
```